# React date countdown timer with input

Tags: reactjs, date, timer, countdown, difference

Hello I have one problem, I created component in which we can get difference between seconds that we type and actual seconds.

Until this point it is ok, but problem comes when I want to save state also for minutes and hours.

The state for seconds works, seconds countdown, but when reach for ex. 1 minute, this minute for a while blinks and return back to 0 and seconds go from start, how to fix this please, I would be grateful for any advice, thank you.

> CountdownContext.jsx

```
import React, { useContext, createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { seconds_to_hms } from '../helpers/secondsToHms';
    import { useClock } from '../hooks/useClock';
    
    const CountdownContext = createContext();
    
    export const CountdownContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
      const time = useClock();
      const [timer, setTimer] = useState({ hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0 });
      const [paused, setPaused] = useState(true);
    
      const countdown = () => {
        if (paused) return;
      
        const diff = timer.seconds - (((new Date() - time) / 1000) | 0);
    
        const formattedTime = seconds_to_hms(diff);
    
        const hrs = formattedTime.h;
        const min = formattedTime.m;
        const sec = formattedTime.s;
    
       
        setTimer({ hours: hrs, minutes: min, seconds: sec });
      };
    
     
      useEffect(() => {
       
        let timerId = setTimeout(() => countdown(), 1000);
    
        return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
      });
    
      return (
        <CountdownContext.Provider
          value={{
            timer,
            setTimer,
            paused,
            setPaused,
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </CountdownContext.Provider>
      );
    };
    
    export const useCountdown = () => useContext(CountdownContext);
```

> Timer.jsx -> here we call our CountdownContext values

```
import React from 'react';
import { useCountdown } from '../../contexts/CountdownContext';
import { useColor } from '../../contexts/ColorContext';

const Timer = () => {
  const { timer, setTimer, paused, setPaused } = useCountdown();
  const { plus, setPlus, minus, setMinus } = useColor();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setTimer((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleStartStop = () => {
    setPaused(!paused);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setPaused(paused);
    setTimer({ hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0 });
    setPlus(false);
    setMinus(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="countdown-wrapper">
      <button className="btn-reset" onClick={handleReset}>
        &#x2022;
      </button>

      <input
        className={`timer-input input-hours ${
          plus ? 'plus' : minus ? 'minus' : ''
        }`}
        name="hours"
        value={timer.hours}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <span className="timer-splitter">&#58;</span>

      <input
        className={`timer-input input-minutes   ${
          plus ? 'plus' : minus ? 'minus' : ''
        }`}
        name="minutes"
        value={timer.minutes}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <span className="timer-splitter">&#x3a;</span>

      <input
        className={`timer-input input-seconds   ${
          plus ? 'plus' : minus ? 'minus' : ''
        }`}
        name="seconds"
        value={timer.seconds}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <button
        className={`btn-start-stop ${!paused ? 'start-green' : ''}`}
        onClick={handleStartStop}
      >
        &#x2022;
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Timer;
```

> useClock.jsx -> custom hook for current time, it is used also on
> another places in code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const useClock = (initialTime = new Date()) => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(initialTime);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      setTime(() => new Date());
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
   
  }, [time]);

  return time;
};
```

> secondsToHms.js -> helper for formatting numbers to time

```
export const seconds_to_hms = (value) => {
  const value_absolute = Math.abs(Number(value));
  let h = Math.floor(value_absolute / 3600);
  let m = Math.floor((value_absolute % 3600) / 60);
  let s = Math.floor((value_absolute % 3600) % 60);

  const value_negative = value < 0;

  if (value_negative) {
    h = '-' + h;
    m = '-' + m;
    s = '-' + s;
  }

  return { h, m, s };
};
```